# How to define Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS) step to copy zip file from source to destination under Teamcity build step?

Tags: windows, powershell, teamcity, microsoft-bits

There is a scenario in which I have to define a build step under Teamcity deploy job configuration. Wherein a compressed file needs to copy from shared drive to udeploy. But firstly I am trying to copy to local drive(WINDOWS OS) for testing.

I am using below command to perform the operation in POWERSHELL, its working fine as expected locally.

Start-BitsTransfer -Source \Shared_Drive_Path\File_Name.zip -Destination Destination_Path

Now, I need to define this command under Teamcity Deploy Job Configuration for its execution.

What configuration i will be requiring to achieve this thing.

Anybody suggest here.

Thanks in advance....... !!

Comment: Maybe [this documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/PowerShell) can help?

Comment: Its not worth for me as the command is working locally from powershell. But unable to work from teamcity